# Overwriting inherent type with own "more" correct - Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function that returns a promise that will be resolved using reflect.

(Promise with, resolve and reject function is queued and then execute)

The input of the function is a method from an object with params as you can see in SingleTask type.

Because I don't return anything inside a promise typescript give the `Promise<any>` as a result.

But in practice, the result is Promise<Returntype `<FIRST PARAM OF SINGLE TASK TYPE>>` - Some function from an object

How can I declare the correct return type

```
type AnyClass = { new (...arg0: any): any }

type SingleTask<V extends AnyClass> = {
  [P in keyof InstanceType<V>]-?: InstanceType<V>[P] extends (...a: any) => any
    ? [P, Parameters<InstanceType<V>[P]>]
    : never
}[keyof InstanceType<V>]

  addTaskToQueue(task: SingleTask<T>): Promise<ReturnType<**What i should put here ?** >> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const instance = this.instances.pop()
      if (instance) {
        this.runTasksInQueue(instance, { task, resolve, reject })
      } else {
        this.queue.push({ task, resolve, reject })
      }
    })
  }
```

[Typescript playground with full code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN0EkQGcxwhIA8AKshAB6Qjq5ogCeAwgDZy64B8yA3gFDJkIAK4BbAEbQAXMPFSog5AHsADmGDK8AflnMt%20KCIRhlUAApwocMREhRcZLgG0AuvwC%20-MI1UoAyqAA5qwQpBwA1sQAahTUELT0qExsHNzIALx8Ss7myKDIERCMyjDIOPiESKS%20EDFcrgC0uuV4BERhtfW5rnE0dMgAFAB0o3CyhIwAlJk8k0pC2si5ADTIlta29o4V7dVd0S7mrg0LyLIgEABu0J7ORSVlu1WdfvXu3rXI4bhRsVT9JIpdicHhZARCAi-WSBEAhMKRepKKAQXDKVg3WSDK5wVgiCAtEQgCIgZQAdxAMwyPCuymA6GREAAVhATFiURwtBMmFSaXSGV5Pn4GCwQfRwcIIGShqNhlYggAGbnTZXIQUIMXIACK%20PxZD6CQGyVFaR4EPybReuFkzw6NTepBcvSybiUAEddRBZD8oo63Jllu4hMoJCy2d9%20EoEAYwEYTGZBiGw2BvTNzZCABbAXDDJOssABvMmJSCoRwTC2pCDXhySTQNZqDQGNWyDDYS0dJxps6hAvAC7yaABhWRoRCYBlQYAQkbmjw3bHY5gZiGwAA3PlkMRawoN8AANT7heLsdgLM50CVDo51QiXAZwaXaVn7O50P5wZTKZnIReE-IFEwBEKAQGQF9cDOUsxwnIZZwMbRhlCOEz0yDIsgARmPRdlygVc9y3HdoD3Q8sJPcDhkvPZUWGW970fKUwPPN9k0TdQ51wZwFVcTjXC-H81X4wDgNA8DINHaDJzgnREISIIULQrJRDrKBSKEHC8M3bclN3fISOyf9M1fSirRou8HyfRjXyLMBWKbPBnGAbiuL4-8-xPISQMsiDFygzMoHJSVpQAUSgfyoEGfiACIAE1lBEZBcD8BAJ2ACB0BUNjmysaxGGQMlgBQ9AJxgFFwGQJCggzAszzgAttKHUoLSvJB6BqgsSnislCGq5RkAQDlIEis5v1-cSOEYIgAKJH1cBwHUIHxCLF2MjobQ7fYHS4FYzhrKEIjWFFkwO1F0RuFtvkRR0lFI2NcvTMdozaADUVULQUCyOAuoK5AACUIBgUITDlVRVFYRgloMv6AfzYYgjsQYVqQNY9p4qZtoM5AiXQf7QDS9GDJR9CgxPb9BJOjEIEGFFErekaxw8PraoQDMhmgMLVOeli2bMOnf2QGBQFxMH9JPR78DAyIA3Ij0FogGi1E-fiYMGPaOcMnMjBAGa5s9BH1ogZHIl5%20mKFYXAUHuxdyMR6jaIfG3jdGnySzGzAfVIZR5sWvaYWCUIfS7WRzH8sRszqP6gJA%2006i4M0zg80CLOD5RQ-NwYqfJm5juTXkRcXMW%2031qWmJtm8Fcd-JJwdvOyKYzXtZAL3KZttZdsiY60Qp7P8zVCuGYgM2Lf49Xhhl-FTLotvfg706Dc5nuPD7yC6aguGwGTyhwak3AWn0No41MCwrBsOxoEcR1SILlR33DStXjqR0Aws8jrIhxdt%20QJZt5485MdoHHLgMkXKTK2Jd9Y3jMomG%20YAQFjgToFdY-lN5OCgUdGuZYQZgyxAQKAa9lRrAAPrgVQLg-ByB5QkKgMqXOlsxwAHo6EAAEwC4EaMAIIpIUTD2epHESTFyzoHdp7XWzgcFrzWBQ0KvF%20IeHxr%20Fenh%20BAA)

Comment: The question "how I can help typescript to understand that I will return the promise with a return type of the return type of function that is inside the first element of the array with is given in input?" is very confusing.  Could you rephrase that to be clearer?  Perhaps with multiple shorter sentences instead of one long one?  Also, your example code doesn't seem to be a [mcve]; could you edit the code so that anyone can put it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?) and see the issue for themselves?  Good luck!

Comment: I rephrase it, I think now is more understandable. Sorry but English isn't my first language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want this sort of behavior:

```
type SomeCtor = new () => { a(x: string, y: number): boolean, b(z: number): string }
declare const q: Queue<SomeCtor>;
const a = q.addTaskToQueue(["a", ["", 1]]); // Promise<boolean>;
const b = q.addTaskToQueue(["b", [1]]); // Promise<string>;
```

I'm also only going to worry about the type signature of `addTaskToQueue()` and not about your implementation and how the implementation interacts with the signature.  From the type system's point of view, with your types as you've defined, I'd do something like this:

```
declare class Queue<T extends AnyClass> {
  addTaskToQueue<S extends SingleTask<T>>(task: S): Promise<ReturnType<InstanceType<T>[S[0]]>>;
}
```

The `addTaskToQueue()` method must be generic, or the best you will do is get another union as the return type, corresponding to the entire `SingleTask<T>` union.  You want the return type to depend on *which* member of the `SingleTask<T>` union was passed in.  Once we have a type parameter `S` corresponding to some member of `SingleTask<T>`, we can express the return type as

```
Promise<ReturnType<InstanceType<T>[S[0]]>>
```

Note that `S[0]` will be the key of `InstanceType<T>` passed in, so we are looking up that property.  You can verify that gives you the behavior I think you want.

So that's the answer to the question as asked.

---

As an aside, it's not clear why your generic `T` is a constructor type that you invariably process with `InstanceType<T>`.  The only thing it looks like you're doing with objects of type `T` is calling `new this.object()`, which specifically assumes that the constructor takes zero arguments.  If so, I'd suggest changing `T` to be the instance type itself, and refer to the constructor as type `new()=>T`:

```
type SingleTask<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends (...a: any) => any
  ? [P, Parameters<T[P]>]
  : never
}[keyof T]

type Task<T> = {
  task: SingleTask<T>
  resolve: (value?: unknown) => void
  reject: (reason: any) => void
}

declare class Queue<T> {
  instances: T[];
  queue: Task<T>[];
  object: new () => T;
  addTaskToQueue<S extends SingleTask<T>>(task: S): Promise<ReturnType<T[S[0]]>>;
}

type SomeType = { a(x: string, y: number): boolean, b(z: number): string }
declare const q: Queue<SomeType>;
const a = q.addTaskToQueue(["a", ["", 1]]); // Promise<boolean>;
const b = q.addTaskToQueue(["b", [1]]); // Promise<string>;
```

That's significantly simpler.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Ch8kkAXATxmQEFgyBhAGxCiiQF4lgIB3JACgB0QkGixQAXEhC0AlOwB8U2gG4ipCsgDKGYFgYQAKswDWAHgBqSCAA8SEYABNWNekxaKOBYsQDaABSQdJGMIMgB7ADMkAElgKBJpRAMNC3kAXQBaAH5JWPjEwxTzeX80q1t7J34hARBJaTI5NkUGtWIspH8AGiQ-EXAIOzQoUzyE4CSikr809LakSS4ANwg0NQBfHxDwqLGC5MpUtMJiBwh4JjRkC+ZWAEUAVwgn0wNyu0dnWkZbxS9vEAOBxGKDGAxhR7PCCmTTvSqsbS6fQgswGeTyPgJUGSTQySR+NBhMAYKDQgBKgweaGAB2hewmhUOaJ8mh8AAY0rN5KpiOsTupKEhNESIHQSGE0OxODx+E0-lI+NZJPFMLoemRFg8wAAjVZ4pDasJhfTSHravgAL01Or1ypIqpwfNO50u1zCcRISAAjpJIS9hZAxRLuWp4O74lIpV7akCUeC-RA+D4AEQgZM9FPppAARk5MmUSAA9IXeoTiaTTIbjRBpCHiGGPQaozHgSZ408nknk9qsz5c2l80WSwSiSToSqdFgQ-g+fhQJBYAhkBSIghxVcHHh+eRBYi9IYTK8PFvvJ0AkFtpEkAZMjlr6U4Z9qsJ6rIFEoyPMOt1ev1IEMRgMUo5lPRYIBWNZeS2UIrxvbcNGvQ80Slf5iCxYwcUnZEkPkeYrigY0VkkPglhABgnjvB5gGMYAwm4YA5SQJYwgwBw8IgAArc4SGIq5mHdV9GnfZjWI2fkzhuK4kBuFgkATI8T28HR8gZCR7zSHlvC9DsIEkFEjx8DT5jCbUuPgHjpV4PhGIMTTiEBVtQXbKEYUfKo92w0EjwxdCcX1Edy3JSlqVpV4WXZTl0U02c0IQgNGWQTwFSVJAJzVJANU4LVdTQfUqxNYAzUta0cv1NLHTUCTXWk8NPR9OSdJhEVaTrGrGxAZsHLjCEdK7NMM2TLN+0HYtS1HCt8prYBWobCNtU62M2x6qEux7DNhoLUaArHUxyundYgA)

Comment: I get an error - "Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.", How can I ensure typescript that I will return what I declare to return? Because in fact, i am not resolving a promise inside of it

Comment: Sorry, I need a [mcve] or I'm not going to be able to look at it.  It is quite possible that you cannot easily get the compiler to verify that your implementation matches the signature.  If you are sure that it does, then you can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry about it.  I was considering such details out of the scope of the question because your question asks "how can I declare the correct return type" which is presumably a question about the type signature and not the implementation.